# react-pdf unexpected token production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-pdf

I'm having some trouble with the production build of react-pdf. The app I'm working on runs fine when being built with webpack-dev-server, but when building the app with the production webpack, the worker for react-pdf isn't working right. There's an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` at `dist1.bundle.js:1`.

From what I found online this indicates that the worker isn't being used. When I used react-pdf's github example on setting workerSrc via cdn, everything works as expected with both prod and dev builds:

```
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`
```

This tells me that the webpack prod build isn't finding the path of my worker, but I don't know why it's not finding it.

I also tried putting the pdf.worker.js file in src under the same folder that my component is in, and I tried downloading the cdn file and putting that in src, but neither of those solved the problem.

import and workerSrc

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

react component:

```
const Item = (props) => {
  const itemName = props.match.params.itemname;
  const pageTitle = itemName;

  const file = props.location.state.url;
  const type = props.location.state.type;

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    numPages: 0
  });

  const onError = (e) => {
    alert(e, 'error in file-viewer');
  }

  const onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    setState({ numPages });
  }

  return (
    <>
    <PageHeader pageTitle={pageTitle}/>
      <div className="container-padding">
        {type === 'pdf' ?
         <Document
            file={file}
            onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
          >
            {[...Array(state.numPages).keys()].map((page) => (
              <Page pageNumber={page + 1} key={page + 1} />
            ))}
         </Document> 
        :type === 'video'? 
        <video 
          controls
          key="video"
          autoPlay
          playsInline
          src={file}
          onError={onError}>
        </video> : 'No file specified'}
      </div>     
      <br />
    </>
  );

}
```

Comment: Do you have any update ? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Try putting pdf.worker.js inside public folder.

Comment: For me, works by downgrading from node 14 to 12